# Difference between System.out.printf and String.format

Tags: java

May I know what is the difference between the two in java? I am reading a book and it uses both methods to display strings.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [first one](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) writes to the [stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) and the [second one](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) returns a `String` object.

Which to use depends on the sole purpose. If you want to display the string in the stdout (console), then use the first. If you want to get a handle to the formatted string to use further in the code, then use the second.

Comment: Both methods print to the console. What's the difference?

Comment: The second one doesn't print to the console. Probably you did it yourself via e.g. `System.out.println(String.format(string, param))`.

Answer (score 8):

`String.format` returns a new String, while `System.out.printf` just displays the newly formatted String to System.out, sometimes known as the console.

These two snippets of code are functionally equivalent:

```
String formattedString = String.format("%d is my favorite number", 42);
System.out.print(formattedString);
```

and

```
System.out.printf("%d is my favorite number", 42);
```

Comment: Even though this post is really old, I just want to add one thing to your answer: The two snippets are not exactly equivalent. System.out.printf does not insert a new line.

Comment: I tried both but it seems neither printf nor format inserts a new line

Comment: @SKumar Correct, but 'thecoder16' is referring to Greg's use of `println`, which, when printing a string, prints said string then terminates the line by adding a line separator (essentially a new line). The use of `printf` doesn't, and neither does the `.format` method.

Answer (score 1):

`String.format` formats strings, doesn't display them. I think you mean `System.out.println(String.format("......", ....))` or some similar construct ?

Answer (score 1):

`String.format` returns a formatted string. `System.out.printf` also prints the formatted string.

Answer (score 1):

These two methods exhibit the exact same behavior. We can use the format(...) with String, Java.util.Formatter (J2SE 5) and also with PrintWriter.

Answer (score 0):

The key different between **System.out.printf()** and **String.format()** methods is that

- **printf()** prints the formatted String into console much like System.out.println() but
- **format()** method return a formatted String, which you can store or use the way you want.

Otherwise nature of use is different according to their functionalities -

**A sample example to add leading zeros into a numbers :**

```
int num = 5;      
String str = String.format("%03d", num);  // 0005    
System.out.printf("Original number %d, leading with zero : %s", num, str);
```