# Java's String/Number/currency formatting capabilities

Tags: java, string, formatting

Is there any easier way of understanding how the numerous ways of formatting in java are related? I get confused of the following:

```
System.out.printf()
System.out.format()
String.format()
System.console.format()
new Formatter(new StringBuffer("Test")).format();
DecimalFormat.format(value);
NumberFormat.format(value);
```

Are the above classes/methods related in anyway? What is the best way to understand the differences and which to use in which situation?

As an example, `System.out.printf`, `System.out.format` and `String.format` all use the same syntax and format flags. I cant see what the difference is in all three of them.

Thanks

Comment: They're just convenience methods wrapping up `Formatter` functionality. (Not sure how `NumberFormat` and its subclasses tie in to that, i.e., which way the relationship flows.)

Comment: @Dave But still a good question why we do have `PrintStream.format` AND `PrintStream.printf` - afaik they were added in the same release and have the same functionality. The jdocs for printf even state: `An invocation of this method of the form out.printf(format, args) behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation      out.format(format, args)`. Strange dublication really

Comment: @Voo I'd guess that someone added all the `printf` stuff to keep the `format` functionality more in line with `print`/`println` etc., but it's just a guess. Most APIs have some amount of duplication, for a variety of reasons--allow different styles, communicate intent differently, etc.

Comment: @Dave Yeah I assume there's no deep mysterious explanation there, so it's just a matter of opinion. Personally I try to avoid exactly these things in my APIs though - to cite the Zen of Python `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`. At least the javadoc clearly states that they're the same so nobody will be wondering "where's the difference?" (well at least nobody that read the docs)

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080112/difference-between-system-out-printf-and-string-format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider downloading the javadocs and source jars for your corresponding Java version because all of your questions can easily be answered by looking at the source and docs.

```
System.out.printf(formatString, args)
```

`System.out` is a [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).  `PrintStream.printf(formatString, args)` is actually a convenience method call to `PrintStream.format(formatString, args);`.

```
System.out.format(formatString, args)
```

This is a call to `PrintStream.format(formatString, args)` which uses a [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to format the results and append them to the `PrintStream`.

```
String.format(formatString, args)
```

This method also uses a `Formatter` and returns a new string with the formatted results of the format string and args.

```
System.console().format(formatString, args)
```

`System.console()` is a [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html).  `Console.format(format, args)` uses a `Formatter` to display a formatted string to the console.

```
new Formatter(new StringBuffer("Test")).format(formatString, args);
```

This creates an instance of a [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) using the string buffer passed in.  If you use this call then you will have to use the `out()` method to get the `Appendable` written to by the `Formatter`.  Instead you might want to do something like:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Test");
new Formatter(sb).format(formatString, args);
// now do something with sb.toString()
```

Lastly:

```
DecimalFormat.format(value);
NumberFormat.format(value);
```

These are two concreate formatters for numbers that do *not* use the `Formatter` class.  [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and [`NumerFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) both have a `format` method which takes a double or `Number` and returns them formatted as a string according to the definition of those classes.  As far as I can tell, the `Formatter` does not use them.

Hope this helps.